# Ctrl + Click to open a file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to be able to open file in code by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on file name inside the editor without select from files side panel or using quick open panel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

For other ones looking for extensions, I suggest this one:
[Open file (by Frank Stuetzer)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Fr43nk.seito-openfile)

I was looking for extensions to open files from path in my pipelines written in **yaml files** and it works pretty well!  :)

You just have to position your cursor under the filename and press alt+P (or right click and "open file under cursor")

Answer (score 1):

You can open a file from within code via  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Click</kbd>  as long as you have `editor.links` set to true in your `settings.json`.

```
{
    "editor.links": true
}
```

or

[image]

**Note:** This functionality is not supported for all languages. When I tested it initially I was looking at HTML.  Check the extension marketplace and you might find something that supports the language you are using. For example, the [Open File From Path extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jack89ita.open-file-from-path) works for PHP.

Comment: Apparently that functionality is not natively supported for PHP. Try installing the  [Open file From Path extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jack89ita.open-file-from-path) and using alt+d to open the file.

Comment: What about virtual environments, are they supported by `Ctrl+click`?